# WebSphere create one bean for two server nodes

Tags: java, ejb, websphere

I have an application, that is deployed on multiple nodes on WebSphere 8.5.5.2
The app contains some business logic that should be executed exactly once (if it was executed on one node, it shouldn't be executed on other nodes).

How can I achieve this?
The only solution I invented, is to create a separate ear with this specific logic and create a separate node for it. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz-scheduler did the trick. It has nice DB-table lock design.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure all nodes to access the same database, then have the code create a row in the database, and if the row doesn't already exist, then perform the code exactly once; committing the create of the database row.

If you need to have the code run exactly once at some schedule/interval, then you could use a persistent EJB timer. If all servers in a cluster are configured to use the same database, then the EJB timer will run on schedule on exactly one of the server instances.

The following information about configuring the EJB Timer server for a cluster my be helpful : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rejb_timerservice_v8.html